# Como obtener el check de un CheckBox de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente DataGridView:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito recorrer ese DataGriView y validar los que tienen el campo seleccionado:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtGrid.Rows)
{
    bool bChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Seleccionar"].Value);
    
    if (bChecked)
    {
        string color = row.Cells["COLOR"].Value.ToString();
        string talla = row.Cells["TALLA"].Value.ToString();
        string referencia = txtReferencia.Text;
      //status = ean.GenerarEan(color, talla, referencia);                                        
    }
}
```

El problema esta en que el registro del DataGridView no me esta tomando el valor del ultimo CheckBox, me dice que es false cuando esta seleccionado.

Comment: Como vas a recorrer ese datagridview dando clic en un boton o cada vez que se marque o desmarque algun checkbox del datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de ir recorriendo el indice de la fila actual, yo lo pondria asi:

```
Int IndiceDGV = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtGrid.Rows)
    {            
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dtGrid.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[4].Value)) //Si el check esta prendido
        {
            string color = dtGrid.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string talla = dtGrid.Rows[IndiceDGV].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string referencia = txtReferencia.Text;                
            IndiceDGV = IndiceDGV + 1; 
                                  
        }
    }
```